# Identify the best method in test data and use it in real data that might have different characteristics?

Tags: error, population

we are trying to identify the best method to measure X in our upcoming study.
We do not have any data from the same populations in the upcoming study but
we have some test data (input data and ground truth) collected in previous studies from
similar population to compare different methods (methods 1-5).

We are planning to select the best method based on the test data collected in previous studies
and use the best method selected for the new data we are collecting in our upcoming study.
However, I am not sure if this evaluation approach is appropriate because the test data collected in previous studies and the data we are collecting in a new study are not coming from the same population and the data characteristics (mean, SD etc) might be different.

In which case, can we simply use the best method we identify using the test data in a new data?
and in which case, we should not use the best method we identify using the test data in a new data
because errors are not negligible.

Please let me know what kinds of books or references I should look at for learning about this too.

Thank you in advance.